# Can 'Quick Search' be removed for certain users?

Tags: drupal, quicksearch

Users don't want Quick Search to be available for certain users. Quick Search isn't available in the Navigation Menu, as one possibility was to use a permission to remove access. We use ACLs and these users are in an ACL group.    Is it possible to remove Quick Search for a group of users? (Civi is at 5.51.3).

Answer (score 1):

Not from UI you can hide it, but via adding JS to remove the section is possible for certain user roles based on permission

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for some no-coding method but answer appreciated.